# Exchange 2003 Strip Email Attachments save to User file

Tags: exchange, powershell

I'm currently using this vba script (locally on client) to strip email attachments from user's folder to and move to user document folder and then replace with a pointer in the email to reference the attachment.

```
Public Sub SaveOLFolderAttachments()

  Dim oShell As Object
  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
  Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Select a Save Folder:", 1)
  If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  ' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

  ' Ask the user to select an Outlook folder to process
  Dim olPurgeFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set olPurgeFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
  If olPurgeFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  ' Iteration variables
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim att As Outlook.attachment
  Dim sSavePathFS As String
  Dim sDelAtts

  For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.Items

    sDelAtts = ""

    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

      While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

        ' Save the file
        sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
        msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

        If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
        Else
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
        End If

        msg.Attachments(1).Delete

      Wend
      If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
      Else
        msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
      End If

      msg.Save

    End If

  Next

End Sub
```

It works great on a small scale however becomes very tedious for multiple users and folders.  I was wondering if there was a way to do this perhaps in powershell that I could loop all users and user folders against the exchange server itself ?

Exchange 2003 / Windows Server 2003

??

Thanks

Comment: You probably should inspect some type of archiving solution.

Comment: I saw a product that was an Exchange Event sink that would store attachments out on a server when a message was received.  Don't remember the name of the product though...